# Keras CNN accuracy is either static or way too high for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a Convolutional Neural Network that can detect whether a person is wearing glasses or not. Unfortunately, I keep getting very strange results no matter which exact settings I use for learning rate, the specific optimizer, etc. With most settings, I notice that the accuracy of my model doesn't change after the second epoch and gets stuck at around 0.56 (which is close to the ratio of one label, 2700 images, compared to the other label, 2200 images). In other runs, with slightly different settings, the accuracy suddenly rockets to about 0.9 and keeps increasing. In both cases, however, the model predicts the exact same classification ('with glasses') each time (even on images that were in the training/validation set), always with a confidence level of 100% (the label is exactly 1 each time).

I'm not all that experienced with Neural Networks for image classification so I wasn't quite sure how to figure out the issue. I tried printing some values from my dataset and their respective labels, and the labels do contain both labels (0s and 1s). Therefore, I assume it's probably an issue with my model but I can't really figure out much myself. I've tried different optimizers (Adam, SGD mostly), smaller and bigger learning rates, different momentum values, less/more convolutional layers and different parameters for the padding and kernel_initializer, different batch sizes... It's still stuck with either the very quickly improving accuracy or the static one.

My code looks as follows:

```py
#parameters
batch_size = 16
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
num_classes = 2
epochs = 10

#training data
train_db = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  `D:\archive\faces\`,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode = "grayscale",
  batch_size=batch_size)

#validation data
val_db = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  `D:\archive\faces\`,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode = "grayscale",
  batch_size=batch_size)

#speeds up the model training
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
train_db = train_db.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_db = val_db.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

#establishing the model
model = Sequential([
layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'),
layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

#different optimizer options
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9)
opt2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

#compiling the model
model.compile(
  optimizer=opt,
  loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
  metrics='accuracy')

#training the model
model.fit(train_db,validation_data=val_db,epochs=epochs)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy() then in image_dataset_from_directory you need to add label_mode='binary' for both the train_db and val_db. For val_db add shuffle=False

Comment: I tried to add this, unfortunately to no avail. What did seem to make a difference is using a much smaller amount of data (10% of the actual dataset), now it actually predicts values between 0 and 1.

Comment: try adding batch_size=batch_size in model.fit